# Error snap.data is not a function with firebase cloud function and onCreate

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have a cloud function that sends a welcome email every time a new user registers in the database.

The function correctly executes everything, sends the emails and these are received by the recipient, so far, everything is fine.

It works when I manually write the email address in the function, but when I want it to get the data from the realtime database, it gives me the error:

**TypeError: snap.data is not a function**

[image]

This is the code of my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "MY_EMAIL",
        pass: "MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD"
    }
})

exports.welcomeMail = functions.database.ref('/paso1/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const _name = snap.data().name;

    return sendWelcomeMail(_name)

});

// aux functions

function sendWelcomeMail(name) {

    return transport.sendMail({
        from: "JohnDoe <sender@test.com>",
        to: "myfriendemail@gmail.com",
        subject: "Hello",
        html: `
        <h1<Hello ${name} </h1>
        <p>nice to seeyou</p>
        `
    })
        .then(r => r)
        .catch(e => e);
}
```

This is my realtime database:

[image]

I have reviewed the documentation several times, I have tested with `snap.val().{uid};` but all without success, I cannot recover the "name" field from the database.

Using `const _name = snap.val().name;` I get the same error

[image]

I am not sure what is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the mistake was.
Indeed, as you have indicated to me, the correct way to extract the data from the realtime database is by using `.val()`

However, I told you in the comments to the answers that I kept returning error.

It didn't work because I wasn't initializing the firebase SDK as an ADMIN, necessary to access, among other things, the realtime database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

I hope my mistake will save other programmers time.

Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is `snap.val()`, not `snap.data()`.  You might be confusing Realtime Database with Firestore.  Firestore uses data() to get the raw data out of a DocumentSnapshot, but that's different than Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. You declare `snap` and then refer to it as `snapshot`. To fix this problem, make sure the declaration and use match.

You're also using `snapshot.data()`, while `data()` doesn't exist on a Realtime Database snapshot (you're probably confusing it with Cloud Firestore).

So combining those two fixes, this should be much closer:

```
exports.welcomeMail = functions.database.ref('/paso1/{id}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => { // this line changed

    const _name = snapshot.val().name;
    ...
```

Comment: It has been a mistake in transcription, I really have declared snap and I also refer to snap. I correct it in the code, thanks.
Even with this correction, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Next up: there is no `data()` member on a Realtime Database snapshot, since `data()` is a method that only exists in the Firestore API. You're looking for `snapshot.val()`. I know you say you tried that already, but unfortunately you're not sharing what went wrong when you did that, and the error message you showed is about `snap.data()`.

Comment: That is very strange.. if i use  const _name = snap.val().name; i get the same error. 
I just tried again to make sure. Add a update to the question

Comment: Please don't say things like "the same error", but be specific and copy/paste the exact error from the logs into your question. Also: please don't post images of textual contents, but post the actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Ok, sorry. When a say the same error, i refer to TypeError: snap.data is not a function, just the picture of the question.

Comment: As said [a few comments up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338633/error-snap-data-is-not-a-function-with-firebase-cloud-function-and-oncreate/59338693?noredirect=1#comment104876113_59338693), you're looking for `snapshot.val()` and **not** `snapshot.data()`. If you use `snapshot.val()` it seems extremely unlikely that the error message will be about referring to a non-existent `data` method. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events, which has an example of an `onCreate` handler. I updated my answer now too.